# Visualforce: is it possible to disable FCKEditor (prevent JS inclusion)?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, fckeditor

I have a VF page like this:

```
<apex:page 
    docType="html-5.0" 
    showHeader="false"
    standardStylesheets="true" 
    applyBodyTag="true"
    applyHtmlTag="false"
>
```

At this page I want to include my own version of FCKEditor instead of getting the a default one included by salesforce (it loads version 4.5.7.1 with some Salesforce-customizations).

I think `standardStylesheets="true"` includes it.

Answer (score 0):

Having `standardStylesheets="true"` is not including CKEditor. The presence of one or more `<apex:inputField/>` bound to an Rich Text field causes the inclusion ultimately.

So if you replace any such apex:inputFields and use `<apex:inputTextarea />` instead on the very same fields, you get plain textareas. Salesforce will not include the CKEditor javascript. So you can include your own CKEditor and be free to customize it as you like or you can use whatever richtext-editor you prefer, e.g. TinyMCE.

For CKEditor I've used `CKEDITOR.replace()` or `CKEDITOR.inline()` to substitute the textarea produced by `<apex:inputTextarea />`. I found it necessary to back-sync the changes made by CKEditor like this

```
editor.on( 'change', function( evt ) {
    $(textarea).val( evt.editor.getData() );
});
```

Note that you have to determine `var textarea` in your usecase.

With that approach you need not care on saving an loading. It feels just as easy as using the Salesforce native Richtext-Editors. And the good thing: the result even supports `rerender`, which the native Salesforce implementation does not.